# Approximating interaction of spin with $N$ different spins as a two level system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

In my studies I have encountered the following Hamiltonian, which is meant to describe some spin (more precisely, spin-1) particle which interacts with $N$ spin-1/2 particles. Neglecting interaction between these $N$ particles, one can write Hamiltonian $H$ in the following form. Here, I am using a physicist's notation.

$$ H = \sum \limits_{k=1}^N \sum \limits_{i=1}^{3} \sum \limits_{j=1}^{3} (A_{ij} (r_k,\theta_k,\phi_k) I_i S_{j,k})= \sum \limits_{k=1}^N \textbf{I}\cdot \textbf{A}(r_k,\theta_k, \phi_k) \cdot \mathbf{S}_k$$

In this equation, $A_{ij} (r,\theta, \phi)$ are real-valued coefficients that represent interaction and they depend on three more parameters which could be interpreted as the distance and orientation from the spin-1 particle. $I_i$ are operators for spin-1 particle, $S_{j,k}$ are operators for $k$-th spin-1/2 particle.

**Goal**: Ideally I would want to approximate this Hamiltonian as a two-particle system with some effective interaction. My goal is to calculate eigenstates and eigenvalues and then to write rate equations, which is possible because I know the experimental setup. I tried solving it numerically and there is no problem finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but it is computationally difficult to compute rate equations.

**Question 1**: Is it possible to average interaction or to approximately calculate average interaction, given that I know it for each $k$? In a sense, are there some methods for such an approximation:

$$ H = \sum \limits_{k=1}^N \textbf{I}\cdot \textbf{A}(r_k,\theta_k, \phi_k) \cdot \mathbf{S}_k \approx \sum \limits_{k=1}^N \textbf{I}\cdot \langle \textbf{A} \rangle \cdot \mathbf{S}_k $$

**Question 2**: Is it possible to effectively replace ensemble of $N$ spin-1/2 particles with a single spin-1/2 particle in the following sense?

$$ H = \sum \limits_{k=1}^N \textbf{I}\cdot \langle \textbf{A} \rangle \cdot \mathbf{S}_k \approx \textbf{I} \cdot \langle \textbf{A} \rangle_{\mathrm{eff}} \cdot \mathbf{S}$$

**My thoughts:**

For the question 1, I feel like when one considers the limit as $N \to \infty$ then one could assume that the spin-1/2 particles are uniformly distributed in the volume around the spin-1 particle and then one could average all three contributions. I am not sure how to do this though.

For the question 2, I feel that all spin-1/2 particles are identical and then one could approximate interaction when $N \to \infty$ as the average interaction times some Gaussian-type function.

I would appreciate any kind of suggestions, ideas, advices and comments.